# Html files showing up blank

Tags: html

So I've decided to learn HTMLas I've put off learning it for a while. I just went to create my first files and it is showing up blank. I don't know why this is happening please help

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB13A.png)

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qhJT.png)

Comment: You have nothing in your `<body>`. What do you expect it to show?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Please copy-paste all code, errors, and stack traces into the body of your question. (The edit toolbar includes a 'code formatting' option that will help you with this.)

Answer (score 1):

If you open your current **HTML** file in the browser and it shows the tab name as [Please work God!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghci1.png) , it's actually working. However, If you want to see something visible in the browser body, then put something inside the `<body>` tag.

You can try the following template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Please work God!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Put something here, And also notice the tab title is "Please work God!"
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```